# Camunda Receive Task

Tags: camunda

I have a question I have defined the following process in Camunda.

[image]

And deployed a servlet in the same application server that allows me to send signals to the deployed process easily.

However, everytime I call the signal method using the process instance id, I get an exception

```
03-Feb-2019 19:36:18.365 ERROR [o.c.b.engine.context] : ENGINE-16004 Exception while closing command context: cannot signal execution 9c3b0cbc-27da-11e9-ae94-0242ac140004: it has no current activity
org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.PvmException: cannot signal execution 9c3b0cbc-27da-11e9-ae94-0242ac140004: it has no current activity
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl.signal(PvmExecutionImpl.java:716)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.SignalCmd.execute(SignalCmd.java:63)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:24)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:104)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.execute(ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.java:66)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:30)
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.RuntimeServiceImpl.signal(RuntimeServiceImpl.java:423)
        at systems.appollo.ams.camunda.signaler.SignalerServlet.doGet(SignalerServlet.java:26)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you send message instead of signal? How is your receive task defined? And what is the arrow inside the receive task? Please send a link to your bpmn.

Comment: Problem solved by calling correlate using the name of the message. The arrow inside the receive task is just the inbound flow, it has a waypoint in the middle of the task and this causes the final arrow to be drawn from inside out. A bug in the modeller I'm using.